# return all possibilities of array with limits for each element

Tags: arrays, c, combinations, method-combination

I would like to create a function in c that takes in an argument that takes in as an argument an array where for each element it gives the range (from 0 to the number stored at the array index), I would like to return all possibilities

an example would be

```
int elements[2] = [2,4]
int *combinations = combinations(&elements, 2) // 2 being the size of elements
```

this would give something along the lines of:

```
0 0
1 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 1
1 2
1 3
```

I've been stuck as to how I should code it, in order to return an array of arrays so that I can test all combinations possible

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the number of combinations?

Comment: @stark its the product of all the elements. in the array elements. Since the size of the array varies creating a loops within loops would not have been possible. So I'm stuck on that point

Comment: so you know how to allocate enough space for the list. Question 2 is given a combination, can you calculate the next combination?

Comment: @stark not necessarily , i don't know how i would be able to do it for an array of length N

Comment: How would you do it for N==1?

Comment: @stark i would return [[0],.., [element[0] -1] ]

Comment: Look at your own table, above.  If you have one line of the table, how do you calculate the next line.  Hint: a single loop starts at the first element ...

Comment: creating a loop for each element would probably be too much no? I would have to code N indented loops?